# Two Foreign Keys in entity framework for same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have two entities: Municipality and RoadSemgents. Municipality is parent and RoadSegments is a child table. I need to have two foreign Keys in RoadSegments from the same table (Municipality).

```
 public class Municipality
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class RoadSegments
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //ForeignKeys
    public int CodeMunicipalityLeft_ID { get; set; }
    public int CodeMunicipalityRight_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CodeMunicipalityLeft_ID ")]
    public Municipality CodeMunicipalityLeft { get; set; }    // LOOK HERE 
    [ForeignKey("CodeMunicipalityRight_ID ")]
    public Municipality CodeMunicipalityRight { get; set; }   // AND HERE
}
```

How do I manage this situation? I have read some posts here for foreign keys to multiple tables but none worked for me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you try to explain it in a more clear and concise way?

Comment: And please, put here only the relevant code parts.

Comment: I'm not sure what the error / problem you are having but if you are using lazy loading you should mark the 2 Municpality as virtual.  public virtual Municipality CodeMunicipalityLeft {get;set;} ....

Comment: Thank YOu for your answer. I`m not using Lazy Loading. I have disabled it. Problem is that the DB is never created.

Comment: Are you getting any exception whatsoever when running the application?

Comment: What do you have in your OnModelCreating() method in your context class?