# Two foreign key elements of the same table on an Entity Framework model?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use Entity Framework to create a database table that will have two columns, one for a *Person* and another for a *Person*. In other words, there will be two foreign keys and each will point to two different records on the same table.

The [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862347/two-foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-for-same-table) that most nearly matches my situation isn't written well and has no answers. [Most questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570916/defining-multiple-foreign-key-for-the-same-table-in-entity-framework-code-first) on StackOverflow and elsewhere deal with collections of many multiple records. In my situation, I *just* need to know how to set up two foreign keys to the same table on a model.

This doesn't look right to me and Visual Studio doesn't like it either, because the code references Person twice.

```
public class Lesson
{
    [Key]
    public int LessonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string studentId { get; set; } 
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string teacherId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Does this look right to you? Am I trying to solve the wrong problem? ...Or, better yet, is there just some syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this look right to you?

No.
Try something like:

```
public class Lesson
{
    [Key]
    public int LessonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public string StudentId { get; set; } 
    public Person Student { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Teacher")]
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public Person Teacher{ get; set; }

}
```